# What's "Web Content" in "top" doing taking up memory?

Tags: firefox, memory

Here's `top` sorted by memory

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                
 4927 shadi     20   0 2227492 320544 127896 S   0.7  8.2   0:42.40 firefox                                
 4984 shadi     20   0 2071260 218544 100976 S   0.3  5.6   0:27.41 Web Content
```

ATM, I only have 1 firefox tab open, from which I'm submitting this question.
There's 4GB RAM in my laptop, so that's 200 MB for 1 tab for `Web Content`.
If I close firefox, `Web Content` goes away (and I have to retype this question .. lol),
so I guess it's related to firefox.

What's `Web Content`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2352693

Web content is a separate process created for a tab so that it is separated from the main process.  This might be done to increase security and speed.  If you kill that process, it'll also kill a tab so I wouldn't mess with it.  Most websites nowadays use tons of memory because they assume that all modern computers have tons of spare memory.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to see what parent process is responsible for the offending spun-off subprocess, you can run `ps -ef | grep <PID>`, where "PID" is the offender's PID as revealed by `top`. For instance, in my case right now I I can determine that Web Process is firefox's fault by doing this:

```
jeff@jbb-dell:~$ top

top - 19:21:13 up 3 days, 21:45,  1 user,  load average: 0,53, 0,59, 0,52
Tasks: 354 total,   1 running, 353 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  7,9 us,  3,2 sy,  0,0 ni, 88,9 id,  0,0 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,0 si,  0,0 st
MiB Mem :  15838,9 total,   4047,6 free,   5705,6 used,   6085,7 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   8192,0 total,   8190,8 free,      1,2 used.   8589,9 avail Mem

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 192311 jeff      20   0   10,7g 379060 118544 S  37,5   2,3   1:06.22 Web Content
      1 root      20   0  171828   9860   6684 S   0,0   0,1   0:03.77 systemd
      2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.05 kthreadd

jeff@jbb-dell:~$ ps -ef | grep 192311

jeff      192311  192141 29 19:17 ?        00:00:08 /nix/store/3j2ls1pg6ap5v04d356qxkf6fmykm6zh-firefox-95.0/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 3 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 5414 -prefMapSize 240917 -jsInitLen 279148 -parentBuildID 20211209203124 -appDir /nix/store/3j2ls1pg6ap5v04d356qxkf6fmykm6zh-firefox-95.0/lib/firefox/browser 192141 tab
```

(I inserted a few extra newlines for readability.)